# How to implement QuartzCode projects into SKScene

Tags: swift, quartzcode

in my app I'd like to add a circle which I've made with QuartzCode in SKScene.

So, I have the two swift files that I got from QuartzCode: "CustomView.swift" and "QCMethod.swift".

How can I implement these files in my SKScene app?

Comment: Are you trying to import an animation or just an image?

Comment: I've An animation

Comment: I don't know QuartzCode but looking at the website it looks like the app does export code for CoreAnimation. This is not something you can directly use in SpriteKit.

Comment: So, I can use this code only in single view applications?

Comment: Again, I'm not an expert of QuartzCode, but I guess it does work with every UIKit app. Not necessarily single view.

Comment: Ok thank you now I understood